# Why are these XSLT 1.0 templates failing to remove nodes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My source HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.2.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="lay-nav-primary">
            <ul class="TabMenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com/">I am not wanted but am not removed.</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="lay-library--header">
            I am not wanted and am removed.
        </div>
        <p>I am not wanted but am not removed.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My XSLT stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove unwanted elements -->

    <!-- successfully removes node with the given class -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' lay-library--header ')]"/>

    <!-- fails to remove 'ul' child node of node with the given class -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' lay-nav-primary ')]/ul"/>

    <!-- fails to remove 'p' nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="p | p/* | //p | //p/*"/>

    <!-- fails to remove 'p' nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="p | p/* | //p | //p/*" priority="9"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't see why the last three templates are not working as I expect when the first is. Thanks.

Comment: Aside - I would not run XSLT on HTML (though posted example is well-formed) as markup rules differ from the more stringent XML standards. If there is a source file to this HTML, consider styling that document, not the output.

Comment: Thanks for the note. There's not a single source I can use as the HTML is the output of a web app's templates. I'm using http://www.html-tidy.org/ to convert from HTML to XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML/XML is in the default namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. Bind that to a prefix and use it in your XPaths.

Also, there's no need to use `//` in the template matches.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove unwanted elements -->

  <!-- successfully removes node with the given class -->
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' lay-library--header ')]"/>

  <!-- successfully removes 'x:ul' child node of node with the given class -->
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' lay-nav-primary ')]/x:ul"/>

  <!--successfully removes x:p nodes-->
  <xsl:template match="x:p"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```